# Nexus 4 Wifi seems disabled with mobile data

Tags: wi-fi, nexus-4, mobile-data

On my nexus four, if I turn on my mobile data Wifi refuses to connect to a network. To connect to a Wifi network I must turn off my mobile data, when I do this all works good short of mobile being off. Does this sound like my settings got wacky somewhere, is there some fix for this issue?

Comment: That's not how my Nexus 4 handles things. Are you running a custom ROM, or perhaps running some other customizations?

Comment: No custom ROM or anything. I have not played much with the phone in anyway.